# Another Easy Separable Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem states: $(y-b)y' = (a-x)$

I solved by:

$\int(y-b)dy = \int(a-x)dx$

$\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}=by + ax + c$

I feel like I should have done more perhaps formatted the answer a little better? Please advise.

Comment: Sure, you should have done that--and you should have stated a question.

Comment: To format your questions in such a way that they are actually readable, please visit this link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I now see my errors. Thanks for your suggestions.